# Xpath element not matched in Selenium but match in Browser Console

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

Hello i have this xpath code and i want to take the link and data.

```
<li class="qTile P-14 Bdbx-1g Bgc-w">
<div class="Lh-16  ">
<h3 id="20151012074222AAY5Tdd" class="qstn-title Fz-15 Fw-b Wow-bw"><a data-rapid_p="1" class="Clr-b" data-ylk="slk:qtitle" href="/question/index?qid=20151012074222AAY5Tdd">Google or Yahoo?</a></h3>
<div class="desc">
  Both
</div>
<div class="long-desc Mah-130 Ovy-s D-n">
  Both
</div>
<div class="Fz-12 Clr-888">
    75 answers
    <span class="Fz-14">·</span>
  <a data-rapid_p="2" class="Clr-b" data-ylk="slk:cat" href="/dir/index/discover?sid=2115500141">Google</a>
  <span class="Fz-14">·</span>
  3 days ago
</div>
```

In this picture is present only the data field, the xpath for take the link of the question works well.
i Try to use this xpath and works well in the browser, but when i use with selenium in Python i have xpath error.

```
 post_elems = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[contains(@class,"qTile P-14 Bdbx-1g Bgc-w")]')

 i = 0
 for post in post_elems:
     data_of_question = post.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"Fz-12 Clr-888")]/text()[last()]')
     url = post.find_element_by_xpath('.//h3/a[contains(@class,"Clr-b")]')
     url_accodare = url.get_attribute('href')
```

Comment: Please post the HTML as text instead of a picture because at some point the picture will no longer be available and the question will be less useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the *XPath expressions in selenium has to point to a tag* and not a text node. In other words, `.//div[contains(@class,"Fz-12 Clr-888")]/text()[last()]` expression is illegal and you have to get that question date in a different way.

For instance, you can get the complete text of the element and use regular expressions to extract the part you are interested in. Example:

```
import re

value = post.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"Fz-12 Clr-888")]').text
match = re.search(r"(\d+ days ago)", value)
print(match.group(1))
```

Or, you can also grab the `outerHTML` of the element and get the text you need by parsing it with, for instance, [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

elm = post.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"Fz-12 Clr-888")]')
data = elm.get_attribute("outerHTML")

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print(soup.find_all(text=True)[-1])
```

There are also, definitely, other options to extract the desired text node.

Comment: I obtain this type of error if i use your first example: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: sure that match.group is good to take the element? i still have this error line 153, in parse
    print(match.group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @RedVelvet could you please print out the `value` variable before calling `re.search()` - what is printed? (might be the post that does not have X days ago in the text - which is, well, understandable :)).

Comment: 2 answers · Programming & Design · 5 months ago

Comment: @RedVelvet yeah that's the reason - our expression is not reliable enough and does not cover all the use cases we can have. Let's try this expression: `(\d+ \w+ ago)$`

Comment: Now works @alecxe 
Thank you very much for your patience and your support! You save me :)
Thanks so much!